# need hint with following excercise

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers and let $b_n=\frac{1}{n}(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)$. I have to prove that $\lim\inf a_n\leq \lim\inf b_n$. I have been thinking about an hour but it seems I just cant find a way to do this. So I need a hint. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it this way: if $\liminf a_n = a$, then all but finitely many of the $a_n$ are greater than or equal to $a$, so what does that tell you about the smallest possible limit point of $b_n = \frac{1}{n}(a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n)$?

Comment: I dont understand why all but finitely many of the $a_n$ are less than $a$, because if $a_n=1/n$ then $\lim\inf a_n=0$, but all the $a_n$ are bigger than 0. Did I understand what you meant?

Comment: I see what you mean; I changed my answer and fixed the typo.

Comment: okey, I understand it now. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!